# IBM Notes combobox choices not updating even when refreshing

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

After saving a specific field in a form, it will store on a view. This view is used by a combo box with a @DBColumn for the choices on another form. This combo box fails to show the recently made field as an option for choices. Even refreshing doesn't do the trick.

The combo box is editable and has "Refresh fields on keyword change" and "Refresh choices on document refresh" checked.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `"NoCache"` parameter in [@DbColumn](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_DBCOLUMN_NOTES_DATABASES.html).

> "NoCache" gets the results of the lookup from the database; no cache
>   is used. If you want to ensure that Domino retrieves the latest
>   information for every lookup, specify this option.